# Expose vs Creating object in Router file of Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

So, I just started with `expressjs 4.0.0` and came across the `express.Router()` object, which is really nice.

Problem is, now that all my routes are in another file, how do I expose an object to the routes file ?

serverjs file:

> ...
> var passport     = require('passport');
> var router = require('./app/routes.js')(passport);  //WILL NOT WORK
> app.use('/', router);
> app.listen(8080);

routes.js file:

> ...
> var express = require('express');
>   var router = express.Router();  //new feature in expressjs 4.0
>   //routes go here
>   module.export = router;

So, how should I access passport object in router file ? Should I create a new object or is there a way to pass the server.js object to router.js file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap your router.js in a function that accepts the passport object as parameter and handles the instantiation of the router also. Then, module.export that function instead of only the router.

EDIT: including example

server.js:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var router = require('./app/routes')(app, passport);
app.use('/', router);
app.listen(8080);
```

routes.js:

```
var express = require('express');
module.exports = function(app, passport){

   var router = express.Router();

   // routes go here
   // do stuff with passport

   return router;

}
```

Comment: could you give me a sample `routes.js` file ?

Comment: I tried that and got the following error:

`var router = require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport);
                                       ^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nightwing/portfolio/nodeAuth/server.js:29:40)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3`

Comment: do you have the proper path to your routes.js? Also, edited a typo so re-check the code.

Comment: I had corrected the `exports` typo. Problem is, `app.use('/',router);` requires an express.Router() object, while we are proving a custom function.

Comment: Then you return `router` at the bottom of the function. That's your object.

Comment: `app.Router()` gives the error `has no method 'Router'`. I edited the routes.js in the answer to make it work. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

this way works

```
    var express = require('express')
  , home = require(_pathtoyourroutes.js)
app.get('/', home.index);
```

//router.js

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    var d = new Date();
  res.render('index', { title: 'Hello world', description:'Hello world this is a awesome site.', stylesheet: 'body.css', jsfile: 'home.js' });
};
```

Comment: I want to use `express.Router()` in my routes.js file, and `app.use('/', router);` in my server.js file.