# Exposing server object in expressJS to another file using module.exports

Tags: javascript, express, require

In an expressJS app I am building I need to expose the server object to another file, so I thought I could do like so from the app.js file to one of my routes

```
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(4021, function () {

    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('http://localhost:%d', port);
});

module.exports = server;
```

app.js file

I have logged the variable from this file and it contains a object with a bunch data in about the server.In my routes.js file I thought would bring it in using require

```
var server = require('../../server');
```

however if I use console.log from route.js on the server variable it is an empty object. Any ideas what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circular dependencies like the one you define can be hard to implement and debug. This isn't going to answer your question specifically, but if the port number is the only thing you need in the route, then I suggest you take a simpler approach. Perhaps a middleware that adds the port number to the request object thereby exposing it to the route:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.port = 4021;
  next();
});
```

Here's another SO question similar to yours: [Expose vs Creating object in Router file of Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23159803/expose-vs-creating-object-in-router-file-of-nodejs?rq=1). Take a look, but I had trouble modifying it to your example.

Comment: I hadn't heard of circular dependencies before and am doing some more research on the term is helping me learn what I did wrong. Thank you